# Mapreduce Program to count total number of words in a file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

A normal word count program the output is word, number Of Words.
In reducer we write context(key,value)
But I want total number of words in file e.g if file has hundread word I want output to be hundred

Comment: [ask] It might be also useful (after you have added your current code), adding the language tag to help experts discover this question. (Though it might just be a duplicate after all, this seems pretty common.)

Comment: Output to be `hundred` or `100`?

Answer (score 1):

It can be implemented using Counters. 
context object has access to these counters.
Counters are incremented at each node and then aggregated finally.

Comment: Can you please explain it through an example?

Answer (score 0):

I guess following should work:
1.Set a dummy key for Reducer in the Mapper for each word.
2.As the Reducer will receive dummy as the key and values will be Iterable you can get the sum of all dummy records.

:-)

Comment: And you can also get the frequency of each word!! I realized that today ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am also quiet new to MapReduce programming and I took the question a kind of a practice. I would suggest the following Mapper and Reducer:

Mapper:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class TotalWCMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, NullWritable, IntWritable>{

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
    IntWritable cnt = new IntWritable(itr.countTokens());
    context.write(NullWritable.get(), cnt);
  }
}
```

Reducer:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class TotalWCReducer extends Reducer<NullWritable, IntWritable, NullWritable, IntWritable> {

public void reduce(NullWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
        Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int sum = 0;
    for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();   
    }
    IntWritable result = new IntWritable(sum);
    context.write(key, result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each word in each line in each file make (key,value) as (filename, 1) and total up 1s in reducer

Comment: Would it not be bad solution because only one reducer would be working? If file is very large then we it would dilute the purpose of using hadoop.

Comment: Can there be anything in which each reducer works and all reducers aggregate there values at the same place. For example , normally there is a global variable where each function could work , is there any thing in mapreduce too where every reducer can work on?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Make your key of the mapper as Text type and emit ***Number of words*** as key and ***Intwritable(1)*** as value.
 And in the reducer use the following code :-

```
public class Word_Reducer extends
        Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum++;
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
```

It will produce the output you need. Accept my answer if this solution fits your case.